# Get the dictionary object in array that has the lowest value in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries as follows:

```
    (
        {
        daysToExpiration = 3;
    },
        {
        daysToExpiration = 87;
    },
        {
        daysToExpiration = 24;
    }
)
```

I would like to retrieve the dictionary with the smallest value for the key `daysToExpiration`. In the above example, the dictionary that should be retrieved would be at index 0 (3 < 24 < 87).

**What I have tried:** looping through the array and getting the value for the key, setting that value to a constant, and then comparing the next value from the loop to that constant and determining if it is higher/lower.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this in Swift? What is the most efficient way to handle this situation?

Comment: That will work, you can also use Array sort(by: element) and sort the objects based on the value. Then return the first object of the array.

Comment: Use the Array min(where) function.

Comment: @llamacorn Any time you find yourself doing something to a whole array, only to use a tiny subset of it, that's a very indication there could be a much more direct and efficient approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.min(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298201-min).

```
let nextToWidgetToExpire = widgets.min(by: { $0.daysToExpiration })
```

Comment: Much simpler approach. Exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.